# Overwriting template in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, http, symfony-2.7, akeneo

Why I can't override the Families in Akeneo which is based on Symfony ?

This is the structure that we have  [image]

And I have successfully override the Categories.

I have followed this guide. https://docs.akeneo.com/1.7/cookbook/category/add-properties-to-category.html

Have just discovered something that could be important for debugging. 
When I type in terminal:

```
php app/console debug:router | grep category
```

Then it displays

```
 pim_enrich_category_rest_list_selected_children GET      ANY    ANY  /enrich/category/rest/{identifier}/selected-children                       
 pim_enrich_category_rest_list                   GET      ANY    ANY  /enrich/category/rest                                                      
 pim_enrich_category_rest_get                    GET      ANY    ANY  /enrich/category/rest/{identifier}                                         
 pim_enrich_categorytree_listtree                ANY      ANY    ANY  /enrich/product-category-tree/list-tree.{_format}                          
 pim_enrich_categorytree_movenode                ANY      ANY    ANY  /enrich/product-category-tree/move-node                                    
 pim_enrich_categorytree_children                ANY      ANY    ANY  /enrich/product-category-tree/children.{_format}                           
 pim_enrich_categorytree_index                   ANY      ANY    ANY  /enrich/product-category-tree/                                             
 pim_enrich_categorytree_create                  ANY      ANY    ANY  /enrich/product-category-tree/create/{parent}                              
 pim_enrich_categorytree_edit                    ANY      ANY    ANY  /enrich/product-category-tree/{id}/edit                                    
 pim_enrich_categorytree_remove                  DELETE   ANY    ANY  /enrich/product-category-tree/{id}/remove                                  
 pim_enrich_product_listcategories               ANY      ANY    ANY  /enrich/product/list-categories/product/{id}/parent/{categoryId}.{_format} 
 pim_enrich_product_category_rest_list           GET      ANY    ANY  /enrich/product/rest/{id}/categories                                       
 pim_api_category_list                           GET      ANY    ANY  /api/rest/v1/categories                                                    
 pim_api_category_get                            GET      ANY    ANY  /api/rest/v1/categories/{code}                                             
 pim_api_category_create                         POST     ANY    ANY  /api/rest/v1/categories                                                    
 pim_api_category_partial_update                 PATCH    ANY    ANY  /api/rest/v1/categories/{code}                                             
 pim_api_category_partial_update_list            PATCH    ANY    ANY  /api/rest/v1/categories
```

And when I type in terminal:

```
php app/console debug:router | grep family 
pim_enrich_family_index                         ANY      ANY    ANY  /configuration/family/.{_format}                                           
 pim_enrich_family_create                        ANY      ANY    ANY  /configuration/family/create                                               
 pim_enrich_family_edit                          ANY      ANY    ANY  /configuration/family/{code}/edit                                          
 pim_enrich_family_rest_index                    GET      ANY    ANY  /configuration/family/rest                                                 
 pim_enrich_family_rest_get                      GET      ANY    ANY  /configuration/family/rest/{identifier}                                    
 pim_enrich_family_rest_put                      PUT      ANY    ANY  /configuration/family/rest/{code}                                          
 pim_enrich_family_rest_remove                   DELETE   ANY    ANY  /configuration/family/rest/{code}                                          
 pim_enrich_mass_edit_family_action_choose       GET|POST ANY    ANY  /enrich/mass-edit-action/family/choose/{operationGroup}                    
 pim_enrich_mass_edit_family_action_configure    GET|POST ANY    ANY  /enrich/mass-edit-action/family/{operationAlias}/configure                 
 pim_enrich_mass_edit_family_action_perform      POST     ANY    ANY  /enrich/mass-edit-action/family/{operationAlias}/perform                   
 pim_api_family_list                             GET      ANY    ANY  /api/rest/v1/families                                                      
 pim_api_family_get                              GET      ANY    ANY  /api/rest/v1/families/{code}                                               
 pim_api_family_create                           POST     ANY    ANY  /api/rest/v1/families                                                      
 pim_api_family_partial_update                   PATCH    ANY    ANY  /api/rest/v1/families/{code}                                               
 pim_api_family_partial_update_list              PATCH    ANY    ANY  /api/rest/v1/families
```

The part where I searched for the families, it is shown without enrich.

Comment: I think you should post more informations regarding the content of your files. 
The link for overriding the categories, also work with attributes, so I suppose it should work with families.

Comment: Hey thanks BatsaxIV. All right, I am going to post it. Just let me know which information do you need ?